# Edit standalone code to receive a parameter

Tags: excel, vba

I have this query that looks for a ")" and shifts it down until it is not next to any data.

```
Sub SeekParen()

Dim c As Range, wheree As Range
Dim whatt As String
Dim TotalCycle As Long, CounterCycle As Long
whatt = ")"
Set c = Range("A1:A10")

Set wheree = c.Find(what:=whatt, after:=c(1)).Offset(0, 1)
    TotalCycle = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c, whatt)
For CounterCycle = 1 To TotalCycle
    If wheree.Value <> "" Then
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Set wheree = c.Find(what:=whatt, after:=c(wheree.Row)).Offset(0, 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next CounterCycle

End Sub
```

I also have a master query that runs each query through all Worksheets.

```
Sub MasterTransformationMacro()

'Dim wb As Workbook
'Set wb = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm")
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Call SeekParen(ws)
    Call SeekParen(ws)
    Call Move(ws)
    Call DoTrim(ws)
    Call CopyA(ws)
    Call ReplaceDelimit(ws)
    Call Split(ws)
    Call DeleteAllEmptyCRows(ws)
    Call DeleteC(ws)
    Call Formuoli(ws)
    Call InsertSystemPath(ws)
Next

End Sub
```

I only can't figure out how to edit SeekParen to fit in to the MasterMacro. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "fit in to the MasterMacro."

Comment: @MattCremeens Sorry for not being clear. I can't figure out how to edit it to include ws so that it will run through all the Worksheets.

Comment: Sub SeekParen(wsToUse as excel.Worksheet) then prefix you range, or any worksheet references with wsToUse. like wsToUse.Range("a1").value

Comment: Are the worksheets you are looping through in the same workbook as the main program or a different workbook from the main program?

Comment: @MattCremeens That's my next challenge haha. As of now it only works in the same workbook but I want it to work in a different workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a worksheet reference to the function, like this

```
Call SeekParen(ws)
```

and modify `SeekParen` to receive it, like so

```
Sub SeekParen(ws as Worksheet)
```

then you should be able to attach the passed worksheet reference to each relevant line in the body of `SeekParen`, like so

```
Dim c As Range, wheree As Range
Dim whatt As String
Dim TotalCycle As Long, CounterCycle As Long
whatt = ")"
Set c = ws.Range("A1:A10")

Set wheree = c.Find(what:=whatt, after:=c(1)).Offset(0, 1)
TotalCycle = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(c, whatt)
For CounterCycle = 1 To TotalCycle
    If wheree.Value <> "" Then
        ws.Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Set wheree = c.Find(what:=whatt, after:=c(wheree.Row)).Offset(0, 1)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next CounterCycle
```

Comment: Ah yeah this is what I tried too but doesn't work. Might just have to rewrite the macro. Thank you though.

Comment: What didn't work about it? What error was thrown and what line was indicated?

Comment: No error - the macro just only runs on the first worksheet

Comment: Instead of using `.Select`. Can you try just referencing the range, like `Set thisRng = ws.Range("A2")` and then try `thisRng.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove`?

Comment: I actually think I didn't realize it was working. Thank you!